# Set an order or precedence when calling functions that may or may not exist

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, template-meta-programming, sfinae

In the process of over-engineering a custom library, I implemented [expression SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae#Expression_SFINAE) to detect and call specific member functions only if they exist. I also let classes overload these functions and then I call the "best" available function based on an order of precedence.

#### Example

The library will accept classes that have defined specific member functions based on a list of available templates:

1. `void print_time(int mins, double secs)`
2. `void print_time(double total_secs)`
3. `void print_time(int mins)`

If a class defines one of the functions listed then the library will call the appropriate function. If a class overloads multiple functions, the first one on the list will be called:

```
class MadLadPrinter {
public:
    void print_time(int mins, double secs); // <- this will get called
    void print_time(int mins);
};
...
MadLadPrinter mlp;
PrinterLibrary::print_time(mlp); // calls 'mlp.print_time(int, double)'
```

The function selection makes more sense in the context of the actual library which contains a large set of callbacks with varying data that classes may or may not need. The code below is a contrived example to illustrate the basic functionality even if the usage in this case is overkill (although it's arguably overkill in the library too).

#### Sfinay Printers:

```
#include <iostream>

// custom struct to ensure functions are called in the correct order
template<int N>
struct Precedence : public Precedence<N - 1> {};
template<>
struct Precedence<0> {};

// The main printer that delegates function calls of other classes.
// Its 'print' function accepts classes that have defined:
// - void print_time(int mins, double secs)
// - void print_time(double total_secs)
// - void print_time(int mins)
// or none of the above.
class PrinterDelegator {
public:
    // The Precedence variable ensures the function with the highest 'N' value
    // gets called. If the function with the current 'N' value is ill-formed,
    // the Precedence struct will cast to its next highest base class until
    // a properly formed function is available.
    template<typename T>
    void print(const T &printer) {
        print(printer, p_);
    }

private:
    // these would all actually be incrementing
    int mins_{3};
    double secs_{22.5};
    double total_secs_{202.5};

    Precedence<3> p_{};

    // The "best" function. Call this if available
    template<typename T>
    auto print(const T &printer, const Precedence<3>&) -> decltype(printer.print_time(mins_, secs_)) {
        printer.print_time(mins_, secs_);
    }
    // Other available functions ordered by importance
    template<typename T>
    auto print(const T &printer, const Precedence<2>&) -> decltype(printer.print_time(total_secs_)) {
        printer.print_time(total_secs_);
    }
    template<typename T>
    auto print(const T &printer, const Precedence<1>&) -> decltype(printer.print_time(mins_)) {
        printer.print_time(mins_);
    }
    // default empty definition allowing for classes that haven't defined 'print_time'
    template<typename T>
    auto print(const T &printer, const Precedence<0>&) -> decltype(void()) {
        std::cout << "nothing" << std::endl;
    }
};

// class with all possible functions. Only the "best"
// one will get called: 'void print_time(int, double)'
class VerbosePrinter {
public:
    void print_time(int mins, double secs) const {
        print_time(mins);
        print_time(secs);
    }
    void print_time(double total_secs) const {
        std::cout << total_secs << "s" << std::endl;
    }
    void print_time(int mins) const {
        std::cout << mins << "m" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Class with two of the function options. The best one here is
// 'void print_time(double)' so that one will be called
class SinglePrinter {
public:
    void print_time(double total_secs) const {
        std::cout << total_secs << "s" << std::endl;
    }
    void print_time(int mins) const {
        std::cout << mins << "m" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Empty class that can still be used even though no functions are defined
class EmptyPrinter {};


int main() {
    PrinterDelegator pd;

    VerbosePrinter vp;
    std::cout << "Should print minutes and seconds:" << std::endl;
    pd.print(vp);

    SinglePrinter sp;
    std::cout << "Should print total seconds:" << std::endl;
    pd.print(sp);

    EmptyPrinter ep;
    std::cout << "Should print nothing:" << std::endl;
    pd.print(ep);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Should print minutes and seconds:
3m
22.5s
Should print total seconds:
202.5s
Should print nothing:
nothing
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/C5MbPU)

Now *assuming* this functionality is actually needed, is there a better way (compile-time) to handle the function selection instead of with the `Precedence` struct? The recursive base class hierarchy seems a bit hacky.

Also, is there a more elegant way to handle the detection and delegation of available member functions in general? Perhaps using C++14/17 syntax?

In order to keep classes lightweight and efficient, I'm intentionally avoiding any virtual inheritance options for the printer classes.

Comment: Having both 2 and 3 as possibly existing members is an abomination, as implicit conversion of the arguments does ignore the different scales.

Comment: @Deduplicator "Abomination" seems a bit harsh  for a contrived example but I agree with the sentiment. I'll make sure to avoid any such faults with the actual callback API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a full review, just an answer on the SFINAE-mechanisms part:

I'd say that your method is perfectly idiomatic. I recommend an approach exactly isomorphic to yours, based on some code I originally saw being used by Eric Niebler:

```
template<size_t I> struct priority_tag : priority_tag<I-1> {};
template<> struct priority_tag<0> {};
```

Notice that by using `size_t` we prevent anyone from entering an infinite regress via `priority_tag<-1>`; although a (`(1<<64)-1`)-level regress is just as bad, honestly, and compilers will catch both in practice after a few levels, so whatever.

I also recommend passing `priority_tag<I>`/`Precedence<I>` by value instead of by const-reference, since it's an empty type. Again since it'll all get inlined I don't think it really matters either way.

---

As for other ways to do the ladder of possibilities: In this case, because you're doing expression SFINAE, I don't think you can get any better. If you were willing to *name* your constraints, via

```
inline constexpr bool is_min_sec_printable_v<T> = ...;
inline constexpr bool is_sec_printable_v<T> = ...;
inline constexpr bool is_min_printable_v<T> = ...;
```

then you could use C++17 `if constexpr` to write:

```
template<typename T>
auto print(const T& printer) {
    if constexpr (is_min_sec_printable_v<T>) {
        printer.print_time(mins_, secs_);
    } else if constexpr (is_sec_printable_v<T>) {
        printer.print_time(total_secs_);
    } else if constexpr (is_min_printable_v<T>) {
        printer.print_time(mins_);
    } else {
        std::cout << "nothing\n";
    }
}
```

---

Notice that `<< std::endl` is just an alias for `<< '\n' << std::flush`, and I don't think your `print_time` function ought to be concerned with flushing the stream, so either `print` ought to flush *unconditionally* after the ladder, or else you ought to push the responsibility for flushing up to your caller (the approach I took).

---

In C++2a, you *might* one day be able to use

```
if constexpr(requires( printer.print_time(mins_, secs_) )) {
    printer.print_time(mins_, secs_);
} else if constexpr ...
```

to eliminate the named concepts `is_min_sec_printable_v` etc. I'm ambivalent as to whether this would be an improvement. (It continues to suffer from the "Write Everything Twice" problem that infects most of modern C++; cf. the `decltype` repetition in your original question.)

Comment: I believe it would be great to mention `std::chrono::seconds` or `milliseconds`, but I'm not sure if the context in the question is at least somewhat related to the problem at hand.